# normalize email when doing find_by(email: ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I normalize the email addresses in a `before_validation`, e.g.:

```
class User
  before_validation do
    self.email = normalized_email
  end

  def normalized_email
    User.normalize_email(email)
  end
end
```

But then I have to do `User.find_by(email: User.normalize_email(params[:email]))` everywhere for instance, and it bit me today when trying to find an user I forgot to normalize the email address, so I would like to have it done automatically.

Ideally I would not overwrite `find_by` and it would work for all the methods, like `where` for instance.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect, but here is what I did:

```rb
scope :by_email, lambda { |email| where(email: Normalizer.normalize_email(email)) }

User.kept.by_email(email).first
User.by_email(email).first!
```

**Edit**: Removed my monkey patch, it was not working anyway

Comment: I would recommend against monkey patching ActiveRecord itself; it has global effect outside your models. Instead, put it in ApplicationRecord which itself inherits from ActiveRecord::Base and make all your models inherit from ApplicationRecord. Also, `where!` is not a documented method. Be wary of relying on it. Be sure to test it so you know if a future version of Rails breaks your assumption. You'd be safer overriding `where`. Finally, since this affects every model you should ensure every model normalizes its emails. If not, only put it in those models which do normalize their emails.

Comment: yeah the monkey patch was not working anyway, still the scope solution doesn't fix my issues and the overload of where or find_by doesn't work on relations, meh

Answer (score 6):

I would just define a special method for this use-case:

```
class User
  def self.by_email(email)
    find_by(email: User.normalize_email(email))
  end

  before_validation do
    self.email = normalized_email
  end

  def normalized_email
    User.normalize_email(email)
  end
end
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
User.by_email(params[:email])
```

Please note that I explicitly didn't suggest using a `scope` for this, because by convention scopes should be chainable and therefore should return `ActiveRecord::Relations` what doesn't work well when you only want to return a single record.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `find_by` in User to ensure this happens consistently.

```
  class << self
    def find_by(*args)
      # find_by can be called without a Hash, make sure.
      attrs = args.first
      super unless attrs.is_a?(Hash)

      # Cover both calling styles, find_by(email: ...) and find_by("email": ...)
      [:email, "email"].each do |key|
        # Be careful to not add email: nil to the query.
        attrs[key] = normalized_email(attrs[key]) if attrs.key?(key)
      end

      super
    end
  end
```

This also covers `find_by!`, `find_or_*`, and `create_or_find_by*` methods. It doesn't cover `where` nor raw SQL.

You could override `where`, but there's some odd caching happening which makes that troublesome.